# How to check if time difference for TIMESTAMPTZ has exceeded 30 days

Tags: postgresql

I have a column called `inserted_at` in my postgres(v15.3) db which of type `TIMESTAMPTZ`.
This value when inserted will always be passed in UTC

I want to retrieve all records for those, 30 days has passed since their last `inserted_at`. I can compare the current date & time(in UTC) with `inserted_at` value.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task description is the biggest riddle here:

> retrieve all records for those, 30 days has passed since their last `inserted_at`.

Assuming you want all rows with a timestamp older than 30 days, then just:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  inserted_at < current_timestamp - interval '30 days';
```

The type `timestamptz` ( = `timestamp with time zone`) stores unique points in time. No need to translate to local time. Just compare to the current timestamp (also type `timestamptz`!) minus 30 days. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Make sure the expression is "sargable". Meaning, don't wrap table column in an expression that would disable index support. In this case: subtract 30 days from the constant input, do not add 30 days to the column value.

To be clear, this information is completely irrelevant for type `timestamptz`:

> This value when inserted will always be passed in UTC

For `timestamptz`, any input is "normalized" to UTC internally, the input format or the appended time zone offset are not stored at all. `timestamptz` is typically the best choice. Again, assuming you didn't confuse `timestamptz` and `timestamp`, and you didn't mess up data input.

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate an index scan on the column, use

```
WHERE inserted_at >= current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - INTERVAL '30 days'
```

Comment: This gets rows with a timestamp *younger* than 30 days, based on column type `timestamp`. I read the question the other way round regarding both, but it's not all that clear.